# Apple Mach-o linker and Dsymutil error right after adding parse sdk

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I was trying to add the parse framework to my project but i have these 2 errors as soon as i added them. I can see the parse framework under the link binary with libraries but for some reason Xcode does not see the framework. I also tried opening a new project and adding the parse.framework folder again,yet the result is the same. Any help is appreciated.

```
Ld /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EatNOW-hhzgxrbjavpslhgovolovnupbeaf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EatNOW.app/EatNOW normal i386
    cd /Library/Developer/California/EatNOW/EatNOW
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EatNOW-hhzgxrbjavpslhgovolovnupbeaf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EatNOW-hhzgxrbjavpslhgovolovnupbeaf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Library/Developer/California/EatNOW/EatNOW -filelist /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EatNOW-hhzgxrbjavpslhgovolovnupbeaf/Build/Intermediates/EatNOW.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/EatNOW.build/Objects-normal/i386/EatNOW.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -lsqlite3.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework "Parse " -o /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EatNOW-hhzgxrbjavpslhgovolovnupbeaf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EatNOW.app/EatNOW

ld: framework not found Parse 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

GenerateDSYMFile /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EatNOW-hhzgxrbjavpslhgovolovnupbeaf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EatNOW.app.dSYM /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EatNOW-hhzgxrbjavpslhgovolovnupbeaf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EatNOW.app/EatNOW
    cd /Library/Developer/California/EatNOW/EatNOW
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EatNOW-hhzgxrbjavpslhgovolovnupbeaf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EatNOW.app/EatNOW -o /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EatNOW-hhzgxrbjavpslhgovolovnupbeaf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EatNOW.app.dSYM

error: unable to open executable '/Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EatNOW-hhzgxrbjavpslhgovolovnupbeaf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EatNOW.app/EatNOW'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where the linker will find the framework. In your target's Build Settings, find the section called Search Paths. In Framework Search Paths field, add the file path of your Parse framework so that it can be located in linking.

Comment: I erased the parse framework from the project, build it(just to make sure), everything worked fine. Then I put the framework added as they described in the walk through also added the folder path to framework search paths, nothing has changed.. Also I tried renaming the file as they suggested here but still no results..  [link](https://parse.com/questions/parseparseh-file-not-found) Any other suggestions?

Comment: That this is a linker issue and not a compile one suggests XCode understands where Parse is at some level. What version of XCode are you using and what are you deploying to?

Comment: What does your file path look like? It should be defined relative to the project folder i.e. "$(SRCROOT)/..." where ... is the remaining file path from your project folder.

Comment: my search path is "$(LOCAL_DEVELOPER_DIR)/California/EatNOW/EatNOW" and $(inherited). Basically Xcode does not see the framework so it doesn't link to it. I wonder if anyone else have this issue